# Cannot Set Property of Undefined Member

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Moving along in [AngularJS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449344852), I get a JavaScript error on the `// ERROR` line below.

Why do I get `Cannot set property 'show' of undefined`?

```
<html ng-app>
<body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js">
      </script>

    <div ng-controller='DeathrayMenuController'>
        <button ng-click='toggleMenu()'>Toggle Menu</button>
        <ul ng-show='menuState.show'>
            <li ng-click='stun()'>Stun</li>
            <li ng-click='disintegrate()'>Disintegrate</li>
            <li ng-click='erase()'>Erase from history</li>
        </ul>
    <div/>

    <script>
    function DeathrayMenuController($scope) { 
        $scope.menuState.show = false;       // ERROR HERE

        $scope.toggleMenu = function() { 
            $scope.menuState.show = !$scope.menuState.show;
        };
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you never define `$scope.menuState`. Instead consider:

```
<html ng-app>
  <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-controller='DeathrayMenuController'>
      <button ng-click='toggleMenu()'>Toggle Menu</button>
      <ul ng-show='menuState_show'>
        <li ng-click='stun()'>Stun</li>
        <li ng-click='disintegrate()'>Disintegrate</li>
        <li ng-click='erase()'>Erase from history</li>
      </ul>
    <div/>

    <script>
    function DeathrayMenuController($scope) { 
      $scope.menuState_show = false;
      $scope.toggleMenu = function() { 
        $scope.menuState_show = !$scope.menuState_show;
      };
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9):

Just working through the same book and came across this issue. Thought I'd add that the following works as well:

```
<html ng-app>
<body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js">
      </script>

    <div ng-controller='DeathrayMenuController'>
        <button ng-click='toggleMenu()'>Toggle Menu</button>
        <ul ng-show='menuState.show'>
            <li ng-click='stun()'>Stun</li>
            <li ng-click='disintegrate()'>Disintegrate</li>
            <li ng-click='erase()'>Erase from history</li>
        </ul>
    <div/>

    <script>
    function DeathrayMenuController($scope) { 
        $scope.menuState = {show: false};       // ERROR HERE

        $scope.toggleMenu = function() { 
            $scope.menuState.show = !$scope.menuState.show;
        };
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just came across this same issue while reading. The ambiguity that the first answer didn't really clear up was that it just used an underline but in doing so created a variable under the scope object, whereas the dot operator was setting an undeclared variable. This answer seemed to more appropriately reflect rectifying the latter situation. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The Errata shows the correction: http://oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0636920028055

```
$scope.menuState.show = false; will give an undefined error 

Added $scope.menuState = {} before to fix the issue i.e.

function DeathrayMenuController($scope) {
  $scope.menuState = {} 
  $scope.menuState.show = false;
...
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. I've been solving the issues as I find them (which has been pretty much every page so far). Its a good book, but it contains a lot of errors.